# Norm of linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given two real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, consider the linear operator $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(x+iy)=\alpha x +\beta y$.

I am trying to figure out the norm of this operator:

$$\| T\|=\sup\limits_{z \in \mathbb{C}\neq 0}\left\{\frac{\|Tz \|}{\| z\|}    \right\}=\sup\limits_{(x,y)\neq (0,0)}\left\{ \left| \frac{\alpha x +\beta y }{ x+iy}\right|\right\}=\sup\limits_{(x,y)\neq (0,0)}\left\{  \frac{\left|\alpha x +\beta y\right| }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\}
$$

I thought maybe using polar coordinates to simplify the ratio as follows:

$$
\frac{\left|\alpha x +\beta y\right| }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\left|\alpha r \cos(\theta) +\beta r \sin(\theta)\right| }{ r}= \left|\alpha  \cos(\theta) +\beta  \sin(\theta)\right|
$$

By using derivatives, this function reaches its maximum when $\tan{\theta}=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$, i.e. :
$$
\| T\| = \left|\alpha  \cos(\arctan{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}) +\beta  \sin(\arctan{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}})\right|=\left| \alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^2}}+\beta\frac{ \frac{\beta}{\alpha}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^2}} \right|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}
$$

Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: I realize the problem is easier to solve by using another different of $\| T\|$ (as Shalop did), namely $ \| T \|=\sup\limits_{z \in \mathbb{C}}\left\{ \|Tz \|\;|\;\| z\|=1    \right\}$: the solution is at the intersection between the circle of radius one centered at (0,0), and the line $\alpha x +\beta y$…very nice resolution method with Cauchy Schwartz proposed by Shalop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x^2+y^2=1$, then by Cauchy Schwarz, $|\alpha x + \beta y| \leq (\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{1/2}$.

On the other hand, $T\big(\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{1/2}}+i\frac{\beta}{(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{1/2}}\big)= (\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{1/2}$.

So, $\|T\| = (\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: We could add that the Cauchy Schwartz is an equality when $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(x,y)$ are collinear, i.e. when $(x,y)=k(\alpha,\beta)$, and the constraint $\| z\|=1 $ imposes $k=1/\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$.